# How to hold jobs for a user so that a total cpu number isn't reached in slurm?

Tags: bash, cluster-computing, slurm, sbatch

I am submitting a bunch of array jobs 4 sets of 5 with 8 cpus each, so 4x5x8=160 cpus total. I would like to keep the running amount to below 100>2x5x8+1x2x8 cpus total, because I need to let others run things. My whole research group is allowed 300 cpus, but I want to stay below 100 so I am not overstepping my share. How do I stop jobs in the queue from automatically running if they will exceed my 100 total cpu (self imposed) max once they run?

My submit script is below and is run 4 times with different input parameters:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --time=13-00:00:00
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=8
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=6000MB
#SBATCH --array=1-5

echo -e "Pwmm\tPwmw\tPmwm\tPmww\n$1\t$2\t$3\t$4" > "params_$SLURM_ARRAY_JOB_ID.txt";

mkdir Games-Surfing-Pwvw_1.0-Pwvv_-1.0-Pmvm_1.0-Pmvv_-1.0-Pvwv_0.9-Pvww_-0.9-Pvmv_0.9-Pvmm_-0.9-Pwmw_$2-Pwmm_$1-Pmwm_$3-Pmww_$4-T_20000000-K_100-M_200-Zone_175; 

/home/jmg367/JULIA/julia-1.8.0/bin/julia -t $SLURM_NTASKS $PWD/surf_probs_re_gill_games.jl $SLURM_NNODES $SLURM_NTASKS $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID $SLURM_ARRAY_JOB_ID;
```

Comment: You are trying to do the job of SLURM. SLURM is the one that must distribute the jobs from the different users in an equitative way (or in any way the administrator decides). Let it do its job. You should just tell SLURM which are your needs (jobs) and let SLURM run them when it sees fit.

Comment: I have other people in my research group and we have only a certain amount of cpus available to us. I want to make sure that I'm not taking more than an equal share. I also want to run something and not have to cancel jobs if I go over, while also not having to continuously check if a number of jobs is finished so I can run more IF it is below the amount which is my equal share. Does that make sense?

Comment: Again, this is precisely the job of a resource manager like SLURM. Your administrator should configure the shares for each group/member and SLURM will take care of prioritizing the jobs of the users so, at the end, the share of resources used is as close as possible to the defined.
If you prefer to do the job yourself, then it is better that you get rid of SLURM and launch the jobs directly while you manage the resources as you wish.

Comment: There are several ways to accomplish what you are asking, and none of them involves the user tweaking the system. Proper priorization, fair share, fair tree, QoS... even just proper partitions. Ask your SLURM administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility for you would be to submit two of the job arrays with a dependency upon the other two (`--dependency=afterany:...`), so that only two job arrays are running at a time. That makes at most 2*5*8=80 CPUs at a time.

```
job_array_id1=$(sbatch submit.sh A B C D)
job_array_id2=$(sbatch submit.sh E F G H)
sbatch --depdendency=afterany:$job_array_id1 submit.sh I J K L
sbatch --depdendency=afterany:$job_array_id2 submit.sh M N O P
```

Comment: This looks like what I want to do. I wonder if it can be refined further: down to the task level within an array. Like: '''--dependency=afterany:$job_array_id1[1-3] submit.sh I J K L''''

Comment: OOOH so it looks like using aftercorr is the same as afterany but at the task id level.